# Linear regression in as a conditional expectation

Tags: linear-model

We can show that the regression for two variables can be written as

$$
E(\mathbf{Y} \mid \mathbf{X}=\mathbf{x}) = \alpha + \beta X
$$

So for example if I consider let the gaussian vector Z=(X,Y)
It means we have

[image]

So

[image]

Is my reasoning correct ?

Comment: If your question is about given $(X, Y)$ is jointly Gaussian, what $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are in terms of $\mu$ and $\Sigma$, then your reasoning is correct.  However, $E[Y|X = x]$ most of the time is not a linear function of $x$, see [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/605062/in-some-sense-is-linear-regression-an-estimate-of-an-estimate-of-an-estimate/605090#605090) for more detailed discussions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct.

You can also rearrange the expression a bit to obtain the linear update formula
$$
\mathbb{E}(Y| X=x) = \mathbb{E}(Y) + \mathrm{Cov}(Y,X) \mathrm{Var}(X)^{-1}[x-\mathbb{E}(X)]
$$

Before we observe $X$, our best estimate of $Y$ is $\mathbb{E}(Y)$. Once we observe $X = x$, we can update our estimate with the formula.